# Terraform: Merge/Re-push Tags into the Source Module

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, amazon-sqs

New to Terraform::
We have a community module for SQS that most of the developers use to spin up a SQS queue and it comes with few(4) tags (community does not have a re-usable Tags module right now).
For my project I need to have extra tags for my SQS queue than the community SQS has, caveat here is that they just did not allow us to make changes in their module.
And I have a tags module that I wrote which I want to use it along with the community SQS module.
Long story short I want to override entire tags block in community SQS module below with my tags module

- use the community module as is and add extra terraform to "re-push" tags

Community SQS Module (named as main.tf):-

```
  resource "aws_sqs_queue" "new_terraform_queue" {
  name                        = var.name
  delay_seconds               = var.delay_seconds
  max_message_size            = var.max_message_size
  message_retention_seconds   = var.message_retention_seconds
  visibility_timeout_seconds  = var.visibility_timeout_seconds
  policy                      = var.policy
  receive_wait_time_seconds   = var.receive_wait_time_seconds
  redrive_policy              = var.redrive_policy
  fifo_queue                  = var.fifo_queue
  content_based_deduplication = var.content_based_deduplication

  tags = {
     environment    = var.environment
     project        = var.project
     application_id = var.applicationId
     purpose        = var.purpose
  }

}
```

Sourcing the above module into my project:

```
module "main" {
  source                      = "git::https://git.url.here/aws/sqs.git?ref=feature/sqs_queue"
  name                        = local.name
  delay_seconds               = var.delay_seconds
  max_message_size            = var.max_message_size
  message_retention_seconds   = var.message_retention_seconds
  visibility_timeout_seconds  = var.visibility_timeout_seconds
  policy                      = var.policy
  receive_wait_time_seconds   = var.receive_wait_time_seconds
  redrive_policy              = var.attach_redrive_policy == true ? local.redrive_policy : ""
  fifo_queue                  = var.fifo_queue
  content_based_deduplication = var.content_based_deduplication

  kms_master_key_id                 = data.aws_kms_alias.kms_sqs_key.target_key_arn
  kms_data_key_reuse_period_seconds = var.kms_data_key_reuse_period_seconds

  # I want to overwrite the Tags in comm module with the below tags
  tags = merge(module.tags.base_tags, module.tags.data_tags, module.tags.extra_tags,
    {
      "Name" = "${local.name}_sqs_tags"
    }
  )
}

module "tags" {
  source = "../../../module/tags"

  environment   = var.environment
  purpose       = var.description
  assetName     = local.name
  backupOwner   = "owner.email"
  dataCustodian = "custodian.email"
}
```

And when i do `Terraform plan` everything plans out really well except the tags, i still only see the 4 tags that the comm module has instead of pushing my tags on top that module

**P.S. if there are other ideas, like asking the community for the relevant edits on their module if overwriting is not possible. I would be very happy and greatly appreciated. Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, I dont think it is possible to override the tags on the module side since it is "hardcoded" to use those 4 tags.
You would have to make a modification on the community module:

On the variable side:

```
variable "tags" {
type = map(string)
default = null
description = "Override tags"}
```

On the resource side (main.tf of module)

```
tags = var.tags == null ? {
     environment    = var.environment
     project        = var.project
     application_id = var.applicationId
     purpose        = var.purpose
  } : var.tags
```

Comment: Nice...... not sure they will let us edit the community module but... worked like a charm though. Thanks